# Oracle procedure is griping about a select query that runs fine outside of the procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
    WITH    Q (L) AS
        (
         SELECT  1 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT  L + 1
         FROM    Q
         WHERE   L < 99
        )
SELECT  MIN(L)
INTO next_priority
FROM Q
LEFT JOIN gxrdird on gxrdird_priority = L 
 and gxrdird_pidm = aPidm_in and gxrdird_ap_ind = 'Y'
WHERE L NOT IN (select gxrdird_priority 
                  from gxrdird where gxrdird_pidm = aPidm_in);
```

This query returns the results that I want when run manually. I'm trying to put it in a package procedure, but I get:

```
51/5  PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored 
55/22  PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got -
```

That corresponds to the line "SELECT L + 1" on the column L is in. Is there any way to declare L as a NUMBER specifically, inside the with clause? I've been googling for an hour, and the few examples of with clauses I can find that have parameters do not declare them as any type.

This is driving me nuts, and there's no simpler query I can come up with that gives me the correct results.

Edit, adding context:

```
  CURSOR xxx_cur IS
SELECT ROWID, GXRDIRD_PRIORITY
FROM GXRDIRD 
WHERE GXRDIRD_PIDM = aPidm_in 
  AND GXRDIRD_AP_IND = 'A' 
AND GXRDIRD_ATYP_CODE IS NULL 
AND GXRDIRD_ADDR_SEQNO IS NULL
ORDER BY GXRDIRD_PRIORITY DESC;

  xxx_rec   xxx_cur%ROWTYPE;
  next_priority         NUMBER;
BEGIN


OPEN xxx_cur;
LOOP
FETCH xxx_cur INTO xxx_rec;
EXIT WHEN xxx_cur%NOTFOUND;

-- Here we should update that particular row, but we can't just increment it.
WITH    Q (L) AS
        (
         SELECT  1 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT  L + 1
         FROM    Q
         WHERE   L < 99
        )
SELECT  MIN(L)
INTO next_priority
FROM Q
LEFT JOIN gxrdird on gxrdird_priority = L and gxrdird_pidm = aPidm_in and gxrdird_ap_ind = 'Y'
WHERE L NOT IN (select gxrdird_priority from gxrdird where gxrdird_pidm = aPidm_in);    

-- The above query found the lowest-numbered unused priority, and now we'll set this record to that.
UPDATE GXRDIRD SET GXRDIRD_PRIORITY = next_priority WHERE ROWID = xxx_rec.ROWID;

-- If the above record was originally 7 and the lowest was 15, now 7 is free and will be used if we loop
-- again.
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(OBJECT_NAME || '.P_RESEQUENCE_INACTV_ACCNTS - Changed priority ' || xxx_rec.GXRDIRD_PRIORITY || ' into ' || next_priority);
END LOOP;
```

Line 51:      WITH    Q (L) AS

Line 55:              SELECT  L + 1

Comment: Odd.  I would have thought it would work.  You could try explicit casting...  `SELECT CAST(1 as INT) as L FROM dual` *(Though I haven't checked Oracle syntax.)*

Comment: I assume you are using at least Oracle 11.2 since that's when recursive subqueries were introduced.  What dot release are you using (this may, of course, be a bug).  Is there a reason that you need a recursive subquery rather than a simple(r) `with q as (select level from dual connect by level < 99)`?

Comment: Already tried that, both with to_number() and cast().

Comment: Looks like we're at: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production. I don't know how else to write the query. I have a table with records that have values (potentially) from 1 to 99, maybe with gaps. Only some of those are important, and of the important ones I have to increment their value starting with the highest, say 11 to 12, then 10 to 11, and so on. But if there already is a 12, then it's 11 to 13, 10 to 11, and so on. I wanted to use this query within a cursor loop, updating one record at a time.

Comment: Can you post some of your pl/sql. How is `next_priority` defined? What line is 51 and 55. Is this the line 1 and 5 of the SELECT?

Comment: Ah and I just remember one more important thing. I don't know what you work with. But in TOAD I always get the first 500 rows. If there is a problem later it does not always come up. Maybe the same in SQL Developer. Try to query the whole table outside the package. Maybe this bring something up.

Comment: Odd - your code compiles and runs fine for me on 11g XE 11.2.0.2.0.  I don't have your table definition, so I just used `INTEGER` for all columns apart from `GXRDIRD_AP_IND`.  I even tried defining functions named `Q` and `L`, but that didn't reproduce the error.

Comment: I don't have access to compile it directly. I submit it to CA SCM, and then some script on the backend does the compile, and I get emailed the output with a big angry red font. Thanks for the confirmation @Luke, it's helpful to know that.

Comment: Oracle doesn't need to have the field type casted (or `to_number()`ed) if you are adding it to an integer as long as the field/column `L` doesn't contain special characters or alphabets. eg. `select '123'+1 from dual;` and `select 'A123'+1 from dual;`. However the error in this case would be ORA-01722 not ORA-00932.

Comment: @Annjawn, I believe you. The database server disagrees though. I think I'm going to give up and rewrite it in plsql.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to generate dummy rows with consecutive numbers. My preferred way of doing that would be:

```
WITH    Q AS
        (
         SELECT  rownum AS l
         FROM    dual
         CONNECT BY level < 100
        )
SELECT  MIN(L)
INTO next_priority
FROM Q
...
```

Please try if this works for you.